# Keras LSTM Dataset Sizing Issue

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I'm working on a project that involves LSTM prediction using the Keras library (run over Tensorflow).

**SETUP**

My training "X" dataset is (initially) a Pandas dataframe containing 52,000+ rows x 19 columns. These 19 columns contain 15 current exogenous readings and one time-step containing 4 previous "Y" readings (y(t-1)). The number of time-steps are subject to change (meaning that if using just one time-step doesn't yield good predictions, I plan on expanding the dataset to 52,000+ x 23). My training "Y" dataset is (also initially) a Pandas dataframe containing 52,000+ rows x 4 columns. Both dataframes are converted to numpy arrays using the following code:

```
trainXArr = np.array(trainX)
trainXArr = np.reshape(trainXArr, (1, trainXArr.shape[0], trainXArr.shape[1]))
trainYArr = np.array(trainY)
```

`print` statements confirm that the processed data are of dimension trainXArr.shape = (1, 52590, 19) and trainYArr.shape = (52590, 4). This is consistent with some of the tutorials I've seen scattered across the Internet with one exception: usually the trainYArr.shape would look like (52590,).

The goal of the model is to make predictions for four points (hence the ,4 in the shape of the trainYArr array). Ideally, all four points would be predicted in the same model rather than creating four separate models with one output each. My model is defined as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(trainXArr.shape[1], trainXArr.shape[2]), activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', 'mae'])
```

**ISSUE**

When I run the model as described in the first code box, I receive the following error: `ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 52590 target samples.` I read this error as saying that the dimensionality of my dataset is out of order.

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

Here are some steps I took to address the problem:

1) Changing the second line (first code box) to `trainXArr = trainXArr = np.reshape(trainXArr, (trainXArr.shape[0], 1, trainXArr.shape[1]))` gives error `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8738, 19)`.

I have no clue where this 8738 number comes from as there is nothing in my code containing length 8738.

2) Adding the line `trainYArr = np.reshape(trainYArr, (1, trainYArr.shape[0], trainYArr.shape[1]))` gives the error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 52590, 4)`.

This suggests that my issue boils down to either the shape of the target dataset (which puts me back at my initial state) or the configuration of the Dense layer.

3) Applying #2 while commenting out the Dense layer yields the error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lstm_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 52590, 4)`.

Nope... It must be the shape of the target data.

4) Keeping the Dense layer commented out and removing the `trainYArr = np.reshape...` line gives error: `ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 52590 target samples.`

And we're back where we started...

**Questions**

After all of this troubleshooting, I have conceded that I am having an issue understanding how set up the data to fit into the LSTM model. My questions are:

1) Is it possible to create a LSTM using Keras that can predict all four outputs at once?

2) How should I structure my data so that I can get the LSTM/Dense model to train?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

LSTM accepts data in the form of

```
(no_of_samples,timesteps,no_of_features)
```

> ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 52590 target samples.

Regarding the original issue, the model thinks that you have 1 sample with 52000 timesteps with 19 features each as the shape of the training data is (1,52000,19). On the other hand, the shape of the supplied labels i.e (52000,4) means that you have 4 labels for 52000 samples. That is why you are getting the mismatch error.

> These 19 columns contain 15 current exogenous readings and one time-step containing 4 previous "Y" readings (y(t-1)).

If I understand it correctly, then the 4  readings of the previous timesteps will also have the corresponding readings for the present timesteps in the other 15 features
i.e (4 readings for previous)+(corresponding 4 for present) + (11 other readings) = total 19 
So your timesteps here are two at a time.

> How should I structure my data so that I can get the LSTM/Dense model to train?

I do not know the application or the context and why you are only passing 4 features for the previous timesteps. But your input shape should be something like (52000,2,no_of_features). Maybe you might split up the inputs to the model. The first input stream will be of the 4 features that have connection with time and go into a LSTM. The second input will be the rest and then you join them after the LSTM. But this is only one of the solutions

> Is it possible to create a LSTM using Keras that can predict all four outputs at once?

Yes you can

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I just need a few clarifications:

With regard to comment 1) I like the setup of the X array (1 sample with 52k timesteps and 19 features). Is there any way to force the Y array to be interpreted as 1 sample of 52k timesteps with 4 (output) features? I tried to do this in Troubleshooting #2, but I ran into issues with the Dense layer.

On Comment 3) Is this offering two different suggestions - one as having recurring time and exogenous variables in separate timesteps in the network and one where I apply exogenous variables to the Dense layer?

Comment: The Y array can just be (1,4) in that case. No need of timesteps. My suggestion was to process the temporal variables (The one which you are supplying for the present and previous) in one brach and the rest of the variables (which you are only for present) in another branch. Then merge them later on. But that is only one solution